# Show bottom border of UITextField in Swift not working with Constraints.

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, constraints, ios-autolayout

My code to show the bottom border only works if I don't use any constraints. As soon as I do so, the bottom line disappears. Any reasons, or solution do this problem? Here is my current code. I've seen quite a few answers to solution, but none are working when I add constraints.

```
 func useUnderline() {

    var bottomLine = CALayer()

    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.frame.height - 1, width: self.frame.width, height: 1)
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
    self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any reasons

Certainly there's a reason. The constraints resize your view (`self`). But they do *not* resize or reposition the layer. So the bottom border is now in the wrong place, possibly outside the view. Your code depends upon `self.frame`, but constraints *change* `self.frame`.

> none are working when I add constraints

Well, it's pretty simple. You need to implement `layoutSublayersOfLayer` in your view, and lay out the border layer there so that it stays where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I just found an old post for objc C. 
You simple put your views in viewDidLayoutSubviews() and everything works just fine.